# How to create a serverless cosmosdb using Azure Cosmosdb SDK?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

how do I create a serverless CosmosDB account using the Python mgmt SDK azure.mgmt.cosmosdb?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-cosmosdb/azure.mgmt.cosmosdb.models.databaseaccountcreateupdateparameters?view=azure-python-preview

I don't see anything relevant in DatabaseAccountCreateUpdateParameters. What are the properties and values I have to specify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not Generally available yet, the only way to create Serverless type is through the Azure portal by Selecting Servlerss option in the account type

Answer (score 0):

I don't know python so I can't guarantee this will work. What I do know is that the serverless feature can be turned on by adding "EnableServerless" as a single item array to the capabilities.

Looking at the unit tests for the python management SDK, I expect that enabling serverless would look like this using this simple example of what you would pass to the create_update_parameters parameter when creating a new account.

```
BODY = {
      "location": AZURE_LOCATION,
      "database_account_offer_type": "Standard",
      "capabilities": [
        {
          "EnableServerless"
        }
      ]
      "locations": [
        {
          "location_name": "westus",
          "failover_priority": "0"
        }
      ]
    }
    result = self.mgmt_client.database_accounts.begin_create_or_update(resource_group_name=RESOURCE_GROUP, account_name=ACCOUNT_NAME, create_update_parameters=BODY)
    result = result.result()
```